# How to convert seconds to into minutes and seconds format (330 to 5:30)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ionic and have tried multiple things but can not get the filter to work. I don't know where to place the code for the filter? I tried in the controller and in the filter.js file but both did not work.

This is the filter I tried:

```
app.filter('secondsToDateTime', [function() {
    return function(seconds) {
        return new Date(1970, 0, 1).setSeconds(seconds);
    };
}])
```

HTML:

```
{{seconds | secondsToDateTime | date:'mm:ss'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your filter should be like below in respective js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    
    <p>filtered msg is :{{seconds | secondsToDateTime | date:'mm:ss'}}</p>
  </body>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.seconds=330;
});
app.filter('secondsToDateTime', [function() {
    return function(seconds) {
        return new Date(1970, 0, 1).setSeconds(seconds);
    };
}])

  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried to follow along but I must have done something wrong...I pasted the filter at the bottom of my controller...everything looks the same...I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: secondsToDateTimeFilterProvider <- secondsToDateTimeFilter

Comment: are you injecting your filter in conytroller?? please compare your code with this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/XmJpMYirhrxQTLfxOwgT?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

[Here the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z18j7o2q/2/)

`Here` I am converting seconds in date format. I think it will useful for you

Comment: I tried but I get this error..it stops me from transitioning to the view  controller that has the filter
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: secondsToDateTimeFilterProvider <- secondsToDateTimeFilter

Comment: are injected $interval provider  in controller and check in ur html instead of filter need to use secondsToDateTime?